# getting Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent while integrating with google pay using xamarin.forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms for my project. When I trying to integrate google pay with app, I am getting "Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent" issue. My code is on below:

GooglePayActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;

namespace GooglePay.Droid.Activities
{
    [Activity(Label = "GooglePayActivity")]
    public class GooglePayActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            try
            {
                string Amount = "1";
                long tslong = JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                string transaction_ref_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10) + "UPI";
                string transaction_ref = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10);
                using (var uri = new Android.Net.Uri.Builder()
                .Scheme("upi")
                    .Authority("pay")
                   .AppendQueryParameter("pa", "xxxxxx@icici")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("pn", "yyyyy")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("pn", "XYZ")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("mc", "1234")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("tid", transaction_ref)
                    .AppendQueryParameter("tr", transaction_ref_id)
                    .AppendQueryParameter("tn", "pay to ram")
                    .AppendQueryParameter("am", Amount)
                    .AppendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                    .Build())
                {
                    Intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                    Intent.SetData(uri);
                    if (IsAppInstalledYourPhone("com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user"))
                    {
                        Intent.SetPackage("com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user");
                        StartActivityForResult(Intent, 9999);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var package = PackageName;
                        ShowToast("GPay is not installed your device");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                ShowToast("Payment Failed");
            }
        }
        private bool IsAppInstalledYourPhone(string packageName)
        {
            PackageManager pm = this.PackageManager;
            bool Installed = false;
            try
            {
                pm.GetPackageInfo(packageName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
                Installed = true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException)
            {
                Installed = false;
            }
            return Installed;
        }

        private void ShowToast(string message)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 9999)
            {
                if (data.GetStringExtra("Status").Contains("Success"))
                {
                    ShowToast("Success");
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error like below:

```
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=pragatigangwar3@icici&pn=manthiram arun&pn=XYZ&mc=0000&tid=de9cc278-0&tr=25ed7488-8UPI&tn=pay to XYZ&am=1&cu=INR pkg=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user }
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in <064cde681fba4dd08eaf8b1bdbbfb8c8>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0005d] in <064cde681fba4dd08eaf8b1bdbbfb8c8>:0 
  at Android.App.Activity.StartActivityForResult (Android.Content.Intent intent, System.Int32 requestCode) [0x00044] in <4a189ea3b82b48a089ac9002b2abc206>:0 
  at GooglePay.Droid.Activities.GooglePayActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0013f] in C:\Users\RAdmin\source\repos\GooglePay\GooglePay\GooglePay.Android\Activities\GooglePayActivity.cs:49 
  --- End of managed Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException stack trace ---
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=pragatigangwar3@icici&pn=manthiram arun&pn=XYZ&mc=0000&tid=de9cc278-0&tr=25ed7488-8UPI&tn=pay to XYZ&am=1&cu=INR pkg=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2071)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1717)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5250)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5208)
    at crc64e4a9dc111dbd1d6c.GooglePayActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc64e4a9dc111dbd1d6c.GooglePayActivity.onCreate(GooglePayActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

I am having google pay on my mobile.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Hi, anybody having answer for this

Comment: I try to test the code you provided. But i do not reproduce the error. Do you get the exception on the line `Intent.SetData(uri);`? If yes, please check your uri.

Comment: This code is working fine on Redmi Note 9 pro for me also. But in samsung s9 plus, it throughs the above exception error